# Form serialize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, serialization

Here is my form's markup

```
                <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" role="form">
                    <div style="width: 190px">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="fullname" name="fullname" id="formFullname" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" id="fromEmail" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="company" name="company" id="fromCompany" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea placeholder="message" name="message" id="formMessage" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="formSubmit">send</button>
                </form>
```

Using jquery 1.10.2

And here is JS

```
 var form = $('#contactForm');

form.submit(function () {
    console.log("form ", $(this).serialize());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url + "ajax/sendmail",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I know that function fires, tested with alert. But console.log doesnt return anything, and during ajax call I don't see anything in POST (Watching with firebug's XHR).

BTW: role="form" is because i'm using Twitter Bootstrap framework

What am I doing wrong?

## UPDATE

data: $(form).serialize() didn't help also

Comment: just to make it sure, what does return `...event.preventDefault();console.log($(this).serialize());...` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you try this :

```
form.submit(function () {
    console.log("form ", $(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

it works just fine. So I think the problem

```
form.on('submit',function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form ", $(this).serialize());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url + "ajax/sendmail",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Because `$(this)` in your code doesn't refer to the `form` but instead refers to `jQuery` on which the `ajax` method is called

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, but first modify your form HTML so that is has an "action" attribute. The nice thing about this code is that it can be used on any form which has a submit button and an action attribute. (i.e. it is not coupled to any specific IDs)

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var data = form.serialize();
        $.post(url, data)
            .done(function() {
                alert('Yay! your form was submitted');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('Uh oh, something went wrong. Please try again');
            });
    });
```

Cheers.